# should I use the present simple when I describe something?

Tags: grammar

I want to consult with my friend about something.

When I talk with her I feel good.
When I'm talking with her I'm feeling good.

I try to explain about some filling something that happen when I meeting with my girlfriend but it not occur right now.

Are They both correct?
What is the difference between them?

thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the word you want is *feel*: "fill" is an entirely different word, not at all appropriate here.

Secondly: it's complicated.

Normally, for most verbs, the "present simple" is used only for timeless or habitual meanings. This means that "When I talk with her" is perfectly good.

With "when" (or "whenever"),  the continuous is also possible: "When I am talking with her" is also good, and presents the act of talking to her as a continuing event.

But the second verb, that is not within the scope of "when" is not normally in the continuous form, because it is habitual in meaning. If you use a continuous form, it is unusual, ("marked", as linguists say) and would convey a very momentary feeling.

So in summary:

> When I talk to her I feel good.

is normal. It says that I feel good from the whole act of talking to her - perhaps while I'm doing it, perhaps at the end as a result of doing it.

> When I am talking to her I feel good.

is possible, but emphasises that it's while I am actually talking that I feel good.

> When I am talking to her I'm feeling good.

is unusual, and puts a very strong emphasis on the moment-by-moment nature of the feeling. It suggests there is something temporary about the feeling - perhaps I will stop feeling good the moment I stop talking to her.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I fixed the mistake of fill/feel :( thanks. and also about the answer it amazing thanks.

Comment: I have question, so When I am talking to her I feel good. what you mean  "emphasises that it's while I am actually talking" ?  because in the first example with present simple it feel that it same. i also emphasises that it's while i actually talking to her not?

Comment: @Alin, in my first example it is not specific when I feel good. Whether it is actually during the talking to her, or maybe the moment I start, or building up over the whole period of talking to her, or even when I contemplate the experience at the end. It might be any of these. In the second, it is saying that it is while talking to her that I feel good. It is often the case that marked tense/aspect forms in English (continuous, perfect, past perfect) are more specific in some way than the unmarked forms.